# Magento Export products from admin

Tags: magento, export, product

I want to export products from admin. When i am selecting entity type "products" its loading whole page layout in entity attribute area.

Please suggest what is the issue here.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It loads the entity attribute area to give you the possibility to skip attributes from being exported.

You can just click 'Continue' at the very bottom to continue product export with all attributes.